# Android application: How do I display users based on what they answer similarly?

Tags: java

I would like for a user to see other users who answered a question the same as them. The questions are not in a quiz or test format. The questions are those to get a sense of one’s personality to see who is the same as them. So far, the user logs in and is prompted to answer the questions and once they are done, they are taken to a screen where I would like to show who also answer the questions the same as them.

I have a database (MySQL) where I have a "users" table. I have the "users" table wrapped into a REST Service. I would like to know if I need to have another table in my database that would contain the questions and answers and wrap that into my REST Service as well or if it is not necessary to have that.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: So am I getting this right? You have users, which answer questions in text form and you want to group them by similarity of the content of the answers?

Comment: The user is displayed questions in which they select one of the available answers. Once they are finished answering the questions,  I would like to show the user the other users who answered any questions they answered the same.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to store your answers in a table in your database. Otherwise, there would be no easy way to find out, what other users have answered.

Let's say you have the following structure of your MySQL database:

```
create table users(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);

create table questions(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);

create table answers(
    user_id int not null references users(id),
    question_id int not null references questions(id),
    `option` int not null,
    primary key (user_id, question_id)
);
```

(Other tables and columns may be required)

In SQL a query to find similar users to a user with the id ID_of_your_user would look somewhat like this:

```
select 
    u.id as similar_user_id, 
    count(*) as same_answer_count 
from users u 
    join answers a on u.id = a.user_id
    join answers a2 on a.question_id = a2.question_id
where a2.user_id = ID_of_your_user and
    a2.`option` = a.`option` and
    u.id != a2.user_id
group by u.id
having same_answer_count >= threshold
order by same_answer_count desc
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the SQL query you have outlined but I am not sure how to wrap that into a REST service. Well I mean I am not sure if I need to create a page on my webhost with a url that is "mysite.com/show_matches" or something like how I have with my users table where I use a page that I already have (I have a login page and a register page)

Comment: You probably need that page `show_matches`. It would need a parameter for the user ID, so it would be something like `mysite.com/show_matches?user_id=42`. That's a design decision, which is entirely up to you.

Comment: Would "ID_of_your_user" be the parameter that you are talking about for the user ID where I would pass that parameter in the SQL statement when writing the SQL statement in PHP?

Comment: Yes, the query finds users which share at least `threshold` answers with the user having the ID `ID_of_your_user`.

Comment: How would I wrap that into a profile page in Android? Like have the users profile (which would include their name and email) who matched with the logged in user being shown rather than just the plain text of the name, email, etc.?

Comment: Well, you encode your result of the query as JSON in your REST service which would give you an array of dictionaries, decode it back on your device and map each element of the array to a table cell.